# React JS - why does a button to be clicked twice?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, button

I have a search function in my ReactJS app that works fine. I've added a "clear search" function which clears the text previously entered in the search text and then requeries with an empty search text, returning to the default selection list.

The text in the search string is saved in properties so that the original search results will be displayed in the selection list when they return from editing an entry.

I would like to code the "clearSearchString" function as follows:

```
   async clearSearchString(value) {
     this.props.updateSearchString('');
     this.searchFromString();
    }
```

and so reuse the searchFromString function below, which just calls the search with whatever the searchString is in properties (which would be reset on the call to clearSearchString);

```
  async searchFromString () {

     this.setState({isLoading: true});

     fetch(`/api/license/search/${this.props.searchString}`, {
        credentials: 'include'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
          licenses: data,
          isLoading: false,
          licensePage: data.slice(this.state.begin, this.state.end)

        }))
        .catch(() => this.props.history.push('/'));
    }
```

However, when I do it that way, the first button click does nothing, but the second button click works correctly. I thought it might have to do with the calls being asynchronous, but removing the async modifier doesn't change the result.

What does work is have them both do the search within their own methods, i.e. duplicate code:

```
   async searchFromString() {

     this.setState({isLoading: true});

     fetch(`/api/license/search/${this.props.searchString}`, {
        credentials: 'include'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
          licenses: data,
          isLoading: false,
          licensePage: data.slice(this.state.begin, this.state.end)

        }))
        .catch(() => this.props.history.push('/'));
    }

   async clearSearchString(value) {

     this.props.updateSearchString('');

     this.setState({isLoading: true});

     fetch(`/api/license/search/`, {
        credentials: 'include'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
          licenses: data,
          isLoading: false,
          licensePage: data.slice(this.state.begin, this.state.end)

        }))
        .catch(() => this.props.history.push('/'));
    }
```

What's the problem? Why does it need two clicks to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State updates are not immediate (see the [React setState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)), so in the code following `this.props.updateSearchString('')`, the parent search-string state passed to your component as `this.props.searchString` has not updated yet. The only reason the approach with the two separate functions works is that `clearSearchString` there does not use `this.props.searchString`, but just fetches `/api/license/search/`.

You can fix this by passing a callback as the second argument to the `setState` in `updateSearchString` (in the parent component), which will get called after the state has been updated.

```
function updateSearchString(searchString, callback) {
  ..
  this.setState(.., callback)
  ..
}
```

And write `clearSearchString` as

```
clearSearchString(value) {
  this.props.updateSearchString('', this.searchFromString);
}
```

Also note that referencing `this.state` in a `setState` argument is an anti-pattern, and should be done by passing an updater function (see the same [React setState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)).

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately got the same result.

Comment: But you do see why your original solution cannot work? There might be something else going on, it's hard to tell without more information. You could try to create a minimal  StackBlitz or CodeSandbox playground that shows the bug, or add a few console logs to make sure the state is what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Ah, right I see what you mean. I'm working on a more pressing issue right now, which may be related - i.e. the user is allowed to double submit, but if I make the submit non-asynchronous, the re-query of the database doesn't initially work - they need to press clear search to see the new license. Maybe because it's pushing to the previous entry on the stack, but anyway, feel free to check it out at [React JS - How to prevent double-submit and trigger search from invoking form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089070/react-js-how-to-prevent-double-submit-and-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Question- Why TouchableOpacity button needs to be pressed twice to hit the API or function in react native ?

Solution:
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';
then add **keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"**

```
 <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"> <ScrollView />
```

Now, it will work perfectly with a single click of a button and the keyboard will also disappear.