# React JS - How to prevent double-submit and trigger search from invoking form

Tags: reactjs, forms, asynchronous, submit

I'm working on a React app which I've realized is allowing double-submits.

To prevent that, I changed the code to not be asynchronous.

But this means when returning to the selection display, the automatic re-query of the database doesn't get triggered.

Here's the corrected submit code from LicenseEdit.js, with the previous async code commented out:

```
//async handleSubmit(event) {
 handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    if(this.handleValidation()){
    } else {
      return;
    }

    const {item, csrfToken} = this.state;

    fetch('/api/license' + (item.id ? '/' + item.id : '') , {
//    await fetch('/api/license' + (item.id ? '/' + item.id : '') , {
      method: (item.id) ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      credentials: 'include'
    });

    this.props.history.push('/licenses');

  }
```

Here's the relevant code from the invoking form (LicenseList.js)

```
 componentDidMount() {

   this.setState({isLoading: true});
       fetch(`/api/license/search/${this.props.searchString}`, {credentials: 'include'})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({
            licenses: data,
            isLoading: false,
            licensePage: data.slice(this.state.begin, this.state.end)
    
          }))
          .catch(() => this.props.history.push('/'));
      }
```

Comment: This might not be the best approach but one thing you can do it check that `this.state.isSubmitting` is `false` before executing the rest of the callback.  Then call `this.setState({isSubmitting: true})` and begin the `async` fetch.

Comment: Thanks - I may give it a shot. I tried one thing, window.location = '/licenses/'; - that seemed to work, but the data from the backend wasn't fully updated due to the fact the AWS S3 client is long-running and therefore probably asynchronous. So I "prefetched" the URL, essentially by creating a routine which took the filename and prepended the bucket. That worked in test, but when in the production environment, I'm getting an error message. So I went to the backup and am quitting for the day. I'll try again next weekend.